# Query with aggregating data from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have three tables in my Oracle db:

**Peoples:**

```
IdPerson PK 
Name 
Surname
```

**Earnings:**

```
IdEarning 
IdPerson
EarningValue
```

**Awards:**

```
IdAward PK
IdPerson FK
AwardDescription
```

- A person can have many earnings.
- An earning  can have many or no any earnings.
- A person can have many awards, one award, or no any award.

I want to make a query that will return 3 columns:

- Surname
- SUM of all EarningValue of person with this surname
- COUNT of all Awards for this person

An important thing is that i also need to display: 0 value if person don't have any award or earning. There is a possibility that person have an award but don't have any earning.

Is it possible to make such query?

Comment: It worked for me when I made test columns and did this code     SELECT Peoples.Surname, SUM(Earnings.EarningValue) as Earnings, COUNT(Awards. IdPerson) as Awards 
    FROM Peoples
    INNER JOIN Earnings
    ON Peoples.IdPerson = Earnings.IdPerson
    INNER JOIN Awards
    ON Peoples.IdPerson = Awards.IdPerson
    GROUP BY Peoples.IdPerson;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.IdPerson, 
       p.Surname, 
       NVL(SUM(e.EarningValue), 0) as SumEarnings, 
       COUNT(a.IdAward) as CntAwards 
FROM Peoples p
LEFT JOIN Earnings e ON p.IdPerson = e.IdPerson
LEFT JOIN Awards a ON p.IdPerson = a.IdPerson
GROUP BY p.IdPerson, 
         p.Surname;
```

What returns this:

```
SELECT p.Surname,
       (SELECT NVL(SUM(e.EarningValue), 0) 
        FROM Earnings e WHERE e.IdPerson = p.IdPerson) as SumEarnings,
       (SELECT COUNT(aIdAward) 
        FROM Awards a WHERE a.IdPerson = p.IdPerson) as CntAwards
FROM Peoples p
```

Comment: There is one problem: the calculated values are too high.. for example one person that have 6 awards, in this calculation have 36 awards

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you just have to join the tables

```
SELECT Peoples.Surname, SUM(Earnings.EarningValue) as Earnings, COUNT(Awards. IdPerson) as Awards 
FROM Peoples
INNER JOIN Earnings
ON Peoples.IdPerson = Earnings.IdPerson
INNER JOIN Awards
ON Peoples.IdPerson = Awards.IdPerson
GROUP BY Peoples.IdPerson;
```

Comment: Might need `coalesce` as well (to display `0` over `null`) for `sum`.

Comment: Group by Peoples.Surname

Comment: I tried it but that query return too much awards and too high EarningsValue in sum. It seems that it is duplicating somewhere. Also one thing: There are some duplicated surnames in my db so it can't be grouped by surname i think.

Comment: Try grouping by id. Tell me if the sums are still high

Comment: Sums are still to high, also the grouping is a problem, becouse i need to show surname, instead of PersonId

Comment: Then don't group them at all, and use inner join this time

Comment: This is impossible, that is the problem - when i use SUM and COUNT, then i have to group by something, otherwise it is error.

Comment: The group by IdPerson.did u try inner join with group by IdPerson?

Comment: 1. You must use `LEFT` join with `coalesce` or `nvl` in case showing 0 if preson has not any record. 2. if you use agregate function you you need to put other columns to `group by` because you get ORA-00937 (If you have Peoples.Surname in `select` and IdPerson in `group by` you get error ORA-00937 too) 3. I recommend to use both columns (Surname and IdPerson) in select and group by.

Comment: Okey, but there is a problem with grouping by surname, becouse there are some different people with the same surname, and then they are going to one record, and it shouldnt be like that.

Comment: That's why I asked if u grouped by idperson

Answer (score 0):

yes of-course it is possible.
you just need to join the tables using multiple join queries and then apply sum() function to get sum of earnings and Count() to count the no. of awards.
Try the below query:

```
SELECT P.Surname,
       Sum(E.EarningValue)AS Total_Earnings,
       Count(A.IdAward)   AS total_awards
FROM   Peoples P
       LEFT JOIN Earnings E
              ON P.IdPerson = E.IdPerson
       LEFT JOIN Awards A
              ON A.IdPerson = P.IdPerson
GROUP  BY P.IdPerson;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's a good idea to offer some comments to help people understand why your answer will solve their problem.